# ¿Cómo obtener la posición de un Combo Box en C#?

Tags: c#

Necesito obtener la posición de un combo box para la siguiente condición:

Si la posición del combo box es 0, que en un textbox1 me aparezca un mensaje, por ejemplo "hola".

La sintaxis que estoy usando y no funciona es:

```
if (combobox1.SelectedIndex == 0)
 textbox.Text="hola";
```

Comment: en que evento pones ese codigo ?

Comment: private void Form_NuevoVehiculo_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
Cuando inicia un form

Comment: pero los items del combo son fijos? si pones un breakpoint en el codigo he inspeccionas el SelectedIndex que valor esta tomando

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recuerda que la propiedad `SelectedIndex` aplica cuando hay una seleccion, si el usuario no selecciono ningun item el valor por defecto es `-1`, por lo tanto si estas validando en el `Load` del form deberias usar

```
private void Form_NuevoVehiculo_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) { 

   if (combobox1.SelectedIndex == -1)
       textbox.Text="hola";

}
```

[ComboBox.SelectedIndex Property](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindex?view=netframework-4.5)